# How to add a single webpage that uses Razor to an Webform application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to add a webpage that uses razor to an existing web application? I have a start page for a web app that I am writing and some of the things that I have to do in particular is have a news ticker feed on the right side of the page, and I'm using JQuery Easy Ticker, but since I am pulling the news from a database, I have no idea how to populate the news ticker on the right handside. I hope I'm being clear...But it looks like it would be easier to use razor for this one page.
So I guess the question is how to do this? should I start a new project just for that one page then copy it to the existing webform application?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, what you can do with Razor, you can do with the aspx syntax as well. 
The easiest solution would be to just open another instance of visual studio and make a dummy project and type the code so you have a greater chance at understanding it.